# Storing XML data to JavaScript variable via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I am calling a PHP file to get the requested XML file and storing its data to a JavaScript variable. Here is the code:

```
var albumXML = null;
<?php $fname = "folder/" . $_GET['getFile'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($fname);
    echo 'albumXML = "' . $contents . '";';
?>
```

But the console shows the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I think it's the starting of the `$contents`'s first tag start. How can I store that data?

Comment: do you have CRLF in the `$contents` variable?. Even if you have an error doing right-click and checking source code helps a ton sometimes to detect strange behaviors

Comment: this php file loaded into the dom via ajax. So the javascript in this file I can't find anywhere ! not in the source code!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $fname = "folder/" . $_GET['getFile'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($fname);
?>
var albumXML = '<?php echo addslashes(preg_replace('@(\n|\r|\r\n)+@', ' ', $contents)); ?>';
```

Comment: same Error ! `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: Try now. I added a `preg_replace` to substitute any newlines by spaces.

Comment: still the same error.! I was before this using the ajax request to get that data and was working fine. But when there is huge xml files. It stops working maybe due to server restrictions. So i tried this direct method but still not working

Comment: @user1820644 Are you using single or double quotes for attributes in your XML?

Comment: there are no attributes in the XML. All simple tag without any attribute.

Comment: @user1820644 Then it should work fine. I just tested it and it's all right.

Comment: @user1820644 Can you paste the output that you get with it?

Comment: It freezes. Because the output is generating by that XML data. So it displays none.

Comment: I've put `echo "alert(" . $fname . ");";` after the `$fname` . But it is not showing the alert !!

Comment: @ jackflash there is \' in some of xml files. Is it fine?

Comment: @user1820644 Just added `addslashes` in order to escape any quote within the XML. That alert doesn't work because you need to wrap the printed variable in quotes this way: `echo "alert('" . $fname . "');";`

Comment: Problem Solved ! As the php file is stored in another directory, AJAX request was made before was from the base in jquery used `foldex/filename.xml` but as php call inside php run from that locaation only `../folder/filname.xml` worked perfectly ! :D thanks for your time ! I appreciate. :)